# Pass values from javascript to jade

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, socket.io, pug

I am using node.js, express, jade and socket.io, I can get javascript code to run on the jade side, but I can't generate html coming from the script. block

I had to update my question based your input. Here are the files:

server.js

```
 app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.sendfile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

io.on('connection', function (socket) {
      socket.emit('news', { hello: res}); // res is the reponse object
      socket.on('my other event', function (res) {
      console.log("socket.io connected and data sent to jade");
      });
    });
```

layout.jade:

```
doctype html
html
  head
    title= title

    script(src='components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js')

script(type='text/javascript' src='https://cdn.socket.io/socket.io-1.0.6.js')
script(type='text/javascript' src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jade/1.11.0/jade.min.js')
script(type='text/javascript' src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jade/1.11.0/runtime.min.js')

  script.
  var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:8898/');
  socket.on('news', function (data) {
    var photo = data.hello.data[0].images.original.url;      
  });


body
    block content
      img(src="#{photo}")  // <--- issue here, creates "undefined" image
```

index.jade:

```
extends layout.jade 

  img(src="#{photo}")  // my problem is here, creating <undefined> tags in html
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could remove the existing component content, and then re-render using jQuery in the jQuery AJAX callback. Something like..

jade:

label#data

After:

script.

```
var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:8898/');
  socket.on('news', function (data) {
      $('#data').text('');    
      $('#data').text(data);
});
```

Comment: perhaps, but my jade template generated from express disappears completely.

Answer (score 0):

Might be a little too obvious but from that example, but I think the JS block inside the script tag needs to be indented. Haven't been able to test that though

```
script.

    var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:8898/');
        socket.on('news', function (data) {
        console.log("socket.io.on data reaching jade");
        console.log(data); // prints fine, but to console only.
        socket.emit('my other event', { my: data }); 
    });
```

Comment: it seems to make no difference.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are extending from layout.jade and index.jade is your child-template. Don't you need to declare that the html is your block content? Like this:

```
extends layout

block content
  #{data}  // my problem is here, creating <undefined> tags in html
      p #{data.stuff}
        img(src="images/bird.jpg")  // works
```

Comment: I updated my question based your input. Please check the comment in the last line of layout.jade The error is "Cannot read property 'hello' of undefined"